# Draw layered arc in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want to create a chart with d3.js, that looks like this arc: http://jsfiddle.net/g0r9n090/111/

The chart should contain multiple layers, like this:http://jsfiddle.net/rq7s1e6j/

How can create a chart, that has this "gap", like the arc, but with multiple layers, like that last fiddle?

Code for last chart:

```
var dataset = {
    apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
    oranges: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
    lemons: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
    pears: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 600,
    height = 400,
    cwidth = 45;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");

gs.selectAll("path").data(function (d) { return pie(d); })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", function (d, i, j) {
            return arc.innerRadius(cwidth * j).outerRadius(cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
        });
```

Any help that could get me anywhere closer to my goal, is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pie layout also allows you to set the start and end angle so you can do the following to create a gap in the pie chart:

```
 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .startAngle(-40 * (Math.PI/180))
    .endAngle(270 * (Math.PI/180));
```

It looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y1no35mw/1/

You can only set the `innerRadius` property on an arc generator, so to add a hollow center what you can do is add an `inner_radius` offset to all the individual arcs like so:

```
var inner_radius = 20;    
gs.selectAll("path").data(function (d) { return pie(d); })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", function (d, i, j) {
            return arc
                .innerRadius(cwidth * j + inner_radius)
                .outerRadius(cwidth * (j + 1) + inner_radius)(d);
        });
```

Once again here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/y1no35mw/2/

Also, if you want the inner radius to have `cwidth` you can just multiply by `(j+1)` and `(j+2)` and then you won't need the `inner_radius` addition.

Comment: Is it possible, to add .innerRadius() to the pie-object aswell? Or how would I go about making the center of the chart hollow? @cyon

Comment: @JesperBaungårdBruunHansen I'll edit my answer to add a way to make the center hollow.

Comment: Thanks again for a precise answer! @cyon I guess I need to read some documentation for the d, i, and j parameters the functions are passing.